# Best way to check if System.Type is a descendant of a given class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, type-systems, system.type

Consider the following code:

```
public class A 
{
}  

public class B : A 
{
}  

public class C : B 
{
}  

class D  
{  
    public static bool IsDescendantOf(this System.Type thisType, System.Type thatType)  
    {  
        /// ??? 
    } 

    void Main()
    {
        A cValue = new C();
        C.GetType().IsDescendantOf(cValue.GetType());
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement IsDescendantOf?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Type.IsSubclassOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) Determines whether the class represented by the current Type derives from the class represented by the specified Type.

Comment: Hmm... That should work well too. Now I'm curious what's the difference between Type.IsAssgnableFrom and Type.IsSubclassOf?

Comment: type1.IsAssignableFrom(type2) will work if type1 is an interface

Comment: Now I guess that Type.IsSubclassOf() is more like what i was looking for. :) Thank you.

Comment: ... 'couse in my case System.Type can be only a Class.

Comment: @sh0gged [Here is the difference](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/type-issubclssof-and-type-isassignablefrom/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available in WinUAP projects. :/

Answer (score 16):

You are probably looking for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

Comment: This is useful, but it will return `true` if both the types are the same. There are some differences between assignment compatibility and inheritance. I also find it harder to read than `IsSubClassOf`.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this doesn't directly answer your question, but you might consider using this instead of the method in your example:

```
public static bool IsDescendantOf<T>(this object o)
{
    if(o == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    return typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(o.GetType());
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
C c = new C();
c.IsDescendantOf<A>();
```

Also, to answer your question about the difference between Type.IsSubclassOf and Type.IsAssignableFrom - IsAssignableFrom is weaker in the sense that if you have two objects a and b such that this is valid:

```
a = b;
```

Then `typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(b.GetType())` is true - so a could be a subclass of b, or an interface type.

In contrast, `a.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(B))` would only return true if a were a subclass of b. Given the name of your extension method, I'd say you should use IsSubclassOf instead of IsAssignable to;

Comment: Is your second-last paragraph correct? I thought `a.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(b))` would be true if `a = b;` was valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this [Type.IsSubclassOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)

Edit:

I don't know your requirements but may be thats the best way:

```
bool isDescendant = cValue is C;
```