# How to find out if (Type is Type) C#

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I am working with two types, one generic and the other not.  I don't have instances of objects but I want to find out `if ( MyType is T )` or in other words `if ( MyType inherits T)`

Again, I am looking for:

```
if ( Truck is Vehicle )
```

not

```
if ( MyTruckObject is Vehicle)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if an instance is of a certain Type or any derived types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754858/how-to-tell-if-an-instance-is-of-a-certain-type-or-any-derived-types)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433750/best-way-to-check-if-system-type-is-a-descendant-of-a-given-class

Comment: Note that the [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) method does not work for generic types! [**Take a look at this article**](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/05/get-all-derived-types-of-class.html) for an implementation of the IsSubclassOf method that works for generics as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
if (typeof(Truck).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Vehicle)))
```

Answer (score 11):

[Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well, given a generic type argument, you could do something like:

```
if (typeof(Vehicle).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) 
{

}
```

Or, apply a constraint to a method to ensure it:

```
public void DoSomething<T>() where T : Vehicle 
{

}
```